# No Python documentation found for 'file'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, pydoc

In Powershell I have typed **$ python -m pydoc file** but I didn't get the python documentation of file. Instead I got the message ***No Python documentation found for 'file'***. What does it mean and how can I deal with it?

Comment: Read the [Python documentation](https://www.python.org/doc/) online...

Answer (score 2):

python -m pydoc "name" ...
Show text documentation on something.   may be the name of a
Python keyword, topic, function, module, or package, or a dotted
reference to a class or function within a module or module in a
package.  If  contains a '/', it is used as the path to a
Python source file to document. If name is 'keywords', 'topics',
or 'modules', a listing of these things is displayed.

python -m pydoc -k "keyword"..
Search for a keyword in the synopsis lines of all available modules.